# How to place list markers (tag <li>) opposite the first line of li paragraph if it consists of few lines

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a list with li tags. While I am decreasing screen width, these li lines are getting split by several ones, so that list markers are getting in the middle of them. How to place them in front of the first line, if there are several ones from the same li tag.

https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2019/11/12/5f2985128f9cc90c861e7623e23a387b-full.png - screenshot

I can use li:before and place it with margins, but with different widths these lines get split by different number of lines, so I have to place this list marker on a new place every time with media queries. I think I can give list-style-type: none. And list-style-type: square to the first lie of li tag using something like li:first-child (meaning first line). But that doesn't help, because CSS 3 thinks that first child is just the first li from all in ul tag, but not the first line in each of li tag.

html:

```
<ul class="teach"> blablabla:
                <li>blablabla</li>
                <li>blablabla</li>
                <li>blablabla</li>
                <li>blablabla</li>
                <li>blablabla</li>
            </ul>
```

css:

```
.teach {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: square;
}

.teach>li {
  position: relative;

}

.teach>li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -20px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  background: #fb765f;
}

// these lines down below don't work in appropriate way as it should

.teach>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.teach>li:first-child {
  list-style-type: square;
}

// so I've just got rid of them
```

I expect markers to be opposite the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are in the middle because you set:

```
.teach>li:before {
    top: 50%;
}
```

You should use fixed top value as:

```
.teach>li:before {
    top: 9px;
}
```

Take a look below:

```css
.teach {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.teach>li {
    position: relative;
}
.teach>li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    background: #fb765f;
}
.teach>li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="teach">
    <li>1 blablabla blablabla</li>
    <li>2 blablabla</li>
    <li>3 blablabla</li>
    <li>4 blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla</li>
    <li>5 blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla</li>
</ul>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/9ws7c1dq/5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```css
.teach{
    padding: 0; list-style: none;
}
.teach>li{
    position: relative; padding-left: 20px;
}
.teach>li:before{
    content: ""; position: absolute; top: 9px; left: 1px; width: 6px; height: 6px; background: #fb765f;
}
.teach>li:after{
    content: ""; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 0; width: 6px; height: 6px; background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="teach"> blablabla:
        <li>blablabla</li>
        <li>blablabla</li>
        <li>blablabla</li>
        <li>blablabla</li>
        <li>blablabla</li>
    </ul>
```